# How do I pass isset value to multiple views with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a `isset()` value that calculate raw count and it displays the count in **admin_messages.php** page I want to pass the same value to **view_home.php** how can I do that?

here is  **view**

```
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <i class="icon-home"></i> Inbox 
        <strong><?php if(isset($count)){echo $count;}?></strong>
    </a>
</li>
```

here is my controller

```
function messages() {

    $data['records'] =  $this->mod_contactus->get_records();
    $data['count'] =$this->mod_contactus->message_count();

    $this->load->view('admin/admin_messages',$data);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The controller is your friend here. Try this - it uses the magic method `__construct()`. Obviously edit this to suit your needs.

```
<?php

 class MyController extends CI_Controller {
   private $message_count = 0;

   // Code called here is executed when the class is initialised, don't forget to call parent::__construct(); to execute the Codeigniter init code too.

   public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();

      $this->load->model('mod_contact');
      $this->message_count = $this->mod_contact->message_count();

   }

   public function messages() {
        $data['records'] =  $this->mod_contactus->get_records();
        $data['count'] = $this->message_count;

        $this->load->view('admin/admin_messages',$data);
   }

   public function another_function() {
        $data['records'] =  $this->mod_contactus->get_records();
        $data['count'] = $this->message_count; // same value

        $this->load->view('admin/another_function',$data);
   }

 }
```